# Jquery function not showing, how come?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get this Jquery count-up function to work but it's not showing up for me, can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

I am using a function created by "mhuggins" (https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo) so I haven't made it myself, just trying to get it to work.

> countup.js

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
        // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

        // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
        var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
            increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

        return $(this).each(function() {
            var _this = this,
                loopCount = 0,
                value = options.from,
                interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

            function updateTimer() {
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

                if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                    options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                }

                if (loopCount >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;

                    if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                        options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
        to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
        onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
        onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And then I am trying to use it with this html page

> test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/countup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('.timer').countTo({from: 0, to: 500});
//--></script>
</head>

<body>
<span class="timer"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

When I fire up the page, nothing happens. The script is working for other people, so it's obviously me who is doing something wrong. I am very new to this so it's not surprising.

Thanks!

Comment: Please set up a working test case or study the JS error-logs in your browsers console for yourself – you first should make sure there are no JS errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `document.ready(function() { // timer code here });`

Comment: Aah yes of course, such a stupid misstake :) Thanks a lot for the quick and precise answer.

Comment: No problem. It's fairly easily done, particularly when it looks like it's inside the timer script itself, but as stated above - the DOM must be ready first, before calling it, or the HTML used in the selector will be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `<span class="timer">` when your script is executed. Add it as a [DOMready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.timer').countTo({from: 0, to: 500});
    });
//--></script>
</head>
```

or execute it in the end of the body:

```
<body>
    <span class="timer"></span>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        $('.timer').countTo({from: 0, to: 500});
    //--></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timer').countTo({from: 0, to: 500});
});
```